# How to open menu vertically on image click(API-7 & above)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have an image in bottom part of the screen.I want that on clicking the image, a vertical menu should open up.I am using android api 7. Screen looks like below image

[image]

**menu created by-**

```
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
        return true;
}
```

**menu**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 >
<item android:id="@+id/en"
          android:title="English"
            />
<item android:id="@+id/pt"
           android:title="Portugess" />
 <item android:id="@+id/es"
        android:title="Spainsh" />
 </menu>
```

Menu show but horizontilly .Please help me!

Comment: is button like Buy and Examples are always there or it should be open when your click on the menu button ?

Comment: @iDroid Explorer buy & examples images are alwaya there.When click on buy or example then a menu will be open.

Answer (score 1):

I Dont know how to use in menu. **But I have done same effect using Layout**. I put code may be this help you.

You have to change layout as per your requirement.

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Buy" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_ex"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Example" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_ex"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="104dp"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="invisible"
     >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Example1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Example2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Example3" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Example4" />
</LinearLayout>
```

top.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="2500"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="200%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:zAdjustment="normal" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AnimationListener {

    private Button btn_ex;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn_ex = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_ex);

        btn_ex.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            private LinearLayout layout_ex;

            public void onClick(View v) {

                Animation movement5;
                layout_ex = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_ex);

                layout_ex.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                // layout3.setVisibility(true); //USE THIS LINE //EDITED

                movement5 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this,
                        R.layout.top);
                movement5.reset();
                movement5.setFillAfter(true);
                movement5.setAnimationListener(MainActivity.this);
                layout_ex.startAnimation(movement5);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing like this,

1. Create one layout (let say menu layout) as per your need in your main layout.

e.g:

```
<RelativeLayout ....>
   <LinearLayout ....> // Your main layout start here

    // your main layout

   </LinearLayout> // Your main layout end here

   <LinearLayout ....>

    // Your menu layout

   </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

1. Define id for the Menu Layout LinearLayout.
2. Initially as the attribute of that menu layout as `android:visibility="gone"` So it is not visible with the main layout.
3. Now while you click on the image, show the that menu with vertical animation as you want.

Hope this idea helps you.  I have done it previous so it is possible and you can achieve your goal with this way.

comment me if any help needed.

Enjoy Coding.  :)